# Spotfire: Count number of marked rows, with IronPython, without iterating

Tags: count, rows, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of marked rows of a table in Spotfire, without iterating over all rows of this table, using IronPython.

I am asking this question because this number of marked rows is already available in the little toolbar at the bottom of the software's window. I search on the Internet and in the Spotfire API but I didn't found anything.

---

Below you will find an image of this toolbar:

[image: example of the toolbar]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found out how to do this:

```
# Get the number of marked rows
nbMarkedRows = Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.GetSelection(TABLE).IncludedRowCount
```

with `TABLE` a reference to your table, as a data table parameter of your script for example.